# How do I achieve same vertex input in vulkan as in opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, vulkan

In opengl in order to draw a quad you need this vertex input data. So I have position `(-0.5f, -0.5f)` and uv `(0.0f, 0.0f)` in the bottom left.

```
float vertices[] = {
    // positions          // texture coords
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   // top right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f    // top left 
};
```

For vulkan it is different as if `position.x` is negated (or `0.0f <-> 1.0f` in `uv.x`).

```
float vertices[] = {
    // positions          // texture coords
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f
};
```

I flipped the viewport in vulkan so I can have `(-0.5f, -0.5f)` in the bottom left.

```
VkViewport viewport{};
viewport.width = renderer.extent.width;
viewport.height = -renderer.extent.height;
viewport.x = 0;   
viewport.y = renderer.extent.height;
```

And now I have this vertex data. For some reason I needed to change sign of both `position.x` and `position.y`, which is very confusing to me.

```
float vertices[] = {
    // positions          // texture coords
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f
};
```

My question is how to archieve uv `(0.0f, 0.0f)` where position is `(-0.5f, -0.5f)`? It would be great if someone would explain to me, what exactly I am missing. Flipped Y is a really well-known topic, but I haven't heard anything about texture coordinates, which is why I feel like I am doing something wrong.

**Update:**

Regular textures can be easily fixed with `stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load` which is common in opengl too, but my framebuffer textures are also flipped, and I don't remember that being an issue in opengl

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly: You state that the uv x-axis is inverted, but then you invert the height of the viewport (which corresponds to the y-axis)?

Comment: @BDL viewport invert has nothing to do with previous statement. It's just a common technique to achieve compatibility between vulkan and opengl (vulkan origin is top-left, opengl origin is bottom-left). I thought that it would fix the uv by itself

Comment: Ok. About the y-axis: Both, the viewport and the uv coordinate origin are flipped compared to OpenGL. OpenGL assumes for both that 0,0 is bottom left, while Vulkan assumes for both that 0,0 is top left. If you invert one (in you case the viewport Y), then you also have to invert the other. I'm not sure why the x-axis is flipped though since this shouldn't be the case.